# What is the difference ( import React from "react"; ) vs ( import React from 'react'; )

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

What is the difference between `' and "` relative to imports:  `import React from "react";` and `import React from 'react';` will it make difference?

Comment: No, it won't. The quoting style doesn't matter.

Comment: It doesn't have any difference. In react 17 (latest version ), If you are making app through Create React App boiler plate or download react through npm, There is no need to import React.

Answer (score 1):

`”` and `’` are completely equivalent in JavaScript in all purposes (strings, import, ecc.). Worth noticing that in json only `”` is valid.